# How to dynamically select columns to query in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to select specific values from a table, by looking at the code from SQLAlchemy `session.py`

```
def query(self, *entities, **kwargs):
    """Return a new ``Query`` object corresponding to this ``Session``."""

    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
```

it does seem that as a function parameter, it **accepts a tuple**. So what I did was:

```
query = ('order', 'location')
columnsStr = 'order, location'
table = 'locations'
sql = "SELECT {0} FROM {1}".format(columnsStr, table)
data = session.query(query).from_statement(sql).all()
```

And it produces this error - `InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '('order', 'location')'`

Why doesn't this work with a tuple?

P.S.

If I change the values of these:

```
query = 'location'
columnsStr = 'location'
```

I do get a result, but only for that single column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
data = session.query('order', 'location').from_statement(sql).all()
```

alternately if you want to keep your tuple structure you can do something like this

```
data = session.query(*query).from_statement(sql).all()
```

the reason is when you pass in a tuple python then puts that tuple in a tuple

```
>>> x = (1,2,3)
>>> def f(*x):
    print x
>>> f(x)
((1, 2, 3),)
>>> f("location", "order")
('location', 'order')
>>>
```

Comment: That is absolutely right, thanks! I did finally catch that you do **need** to unpack your arguments tuple using `*argumentsInTuple` syntax from http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists but thanks a bunch for the answer!